# How can I create an IEnumerable list for just one item?

Tags: c#

I have the following constructor for a class:

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items);
```

I have been populating this with the following:

```
        var AccountId = new SelectList(_reference.Get("01")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(o => o.Order), "RowKey", "Value", "00");
```

Now I would like to populate with one element of data where the data is a list as follows:

```
RowKey = "", Value = "00"
```

How can I make an IEnumerable from the above line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an anonymous type array:

```
var AccountId = new SelectList(new[] 
                { 
                    new { RowKey = "", Value = "00" }
                }, "RowKey", "Value", "00");
```

Answer (score 4):

[Enumerable.Repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx)  is very convenient way to create iterators returning just one element. If you need iterator for 0 items use Enumerable.Empty.

```
Enumerable.Repeat(new {RowKey = "", Value = "00"}, 1);
```